# Python logging - using filters to remove information

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to remove some information while logging to console but then keep that information while logging to a file

Here's a basic example:

```
import logging
import sys

class MyFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        record.msg = record.msg.replace("test", "")
        return True

logger = logging.getLogger("mylogger")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

console = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
console.setLevel("INFO")
logger.addHandler(console)

logfile = logging.FileHandler("log.txt", 'w')
logfile.setLevel("ERROR")
logger.addHandler(logfile)

filt = MyFilter()
console.addFilter(filt)

logger.info("test one")
logger.error("test two")
```

What I'd like to see on console is

```
one
two
```

and then in the log file

```
test two
```

but it's actually just

```
two
```

I'm assuming editing the LogRecord is what's causing this.
Is there a way of achieving what I want or is what I'm trying to do not possible in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you need is a `logging.Formatter`:

```
class MyFormatter(logging.Formatter):   
    def format(self, record):
       return record.msg.replace("test", "")

#...
console.setFormatter(MyFormatter())
#...
```